# why do i have memory leak while doing inheritance of QWidget class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I am new to c++. I am trying to design one class by inheriting base class `QWidget`
but I am getting memory leak while creating this class via new. 
here below I have my code snippet of class and main application

```
#include "QWidget"
#include "QDebug"
#include "ui_myobject.h"

namespace Ui {    
    class MyObject;    
}

class MyObject : public QWidget{    
    Q_OBJECT    
public:       
    explicit MyObject();
    ~MyObject();
    Ui::MyObject *ui; 
};
```

---

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include "ui_myobject.h"

MyObject::MyObject() : QWidget(),ui(new Ui::MyObject){    
    ui->setupUi(this);
    qDebug() << "MyObject Initilised";
}
MyObject::~MyObject(){    
    delete ui;
    qDebug() << "MyObject Deinitilised";    
}

class Application : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT    
public:
    explicit Application(QWidget *parent = 0);    
    ~Application();     
    MyObject *m_MyObject;       
};  

Application::Application(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent),ui(new Ui::Application){    
ui->setupUi(this);    
}
```

i am calling this below function via click release slot of button

```
void somefunction()
    {
      m_MyObject = new MyObject();
                //mAlarm_main->Alarm();    
                m_MyObject->show();    
                delete m_MyObject;
    }


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if (QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0))
    ; // Qt5 uses different graphical backend
#else
    QApplication::setGraphicsSystem("raster");
#endif

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Application w;

    // uncomment this line to remove window frame
    //w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    w.setGeometry(0,0,800,480);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

When I call somefunction I have memory leak in my app I am watching its stack size using top command it continuously increase by `2 mb` after `200 times`my application crashes. I am deleting my object but still some memory leaks occure is there any different way to delete QWidget

If i don't call m_MyObject->show(); function than memory leaks not happen.

Comment: if it is a qobject don't delete it.  pass it a parent when constructing it. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Comment: I passed parent to it but result is same.

Comment: Where do you use `Application` objects? And why do you think that the problem is in calling `somefunction()`?

Comment: Is that the complete code you have shown?

Comment: i have updated code of my main function

Comment: @vahancho i called somefunction() via button slot it creates myobject and delete its but memory leaks occurs i am watching applications memory use via top command .

Comment: didn't you edit ui_myobject.h manually?

Comment: No sir i didn't i designed it using QtDesigner

Comment: The default window limit on windows is 50 over than that your application crashes.

Comment: this is why i want to remove created window using myobject but it leaks memory at     deleting it

Comment: I would try to remove UI components in UI::MyObject form one by one via Designer and check whether the leak remains.

Comment: @wtom i removed  all ui components from form but still memory leaks happen

Comment: is somefunction() a member of Application? replace MyObject *m_MyObject; with std::unique_ptr<MyObject> m_MyObject; and m_MyObject = new MyObject(); with m_MyObject = std::make_unique<MyObject>(); and remove delete m_MyObject; let's see =)

Comment: btw. are all "MyObject Initilised" followed with "MyObject Deinitilised"?

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using exactly? and on which platform (win, mac)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following piece of code you delete just shown widget (method `show' is not blocking). I believe it causes undefined behavior and, probably, the memory leak you are worrying about:

```
  m_MyObject = new MyObject();
  m_MyObject->show();
  delete m_MyObject;
```

Assuming that you need only one `MyObject` in a time, I would suggest to create `MyObject` only once (don't forget to initialize it with `nullptr` by default)

```
if (!m_MyObject)
    m_MyObject = new MyObject();
m_MyObject->show();
```

Another way (*looks like this widget is supposed to be shown as a separate window*) is to set [Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute (see [QWidget::close](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close) for details).

```
    m_MyObject = new MyObject();
    m_MyObject->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
    m_MyObject->show();
```

**Example:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWidget* w = nullptr;
    QPushButton b;
    b.setText("Button");
    b.connect(&b, &QPushButton::clicked, [&w]() {
        w = new QWidget();
        w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true); // ADD THIS LINE
        w->show();
        // delete w; // DON'T DO IT
    });
    b.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: m_MyObject = new MyObject();
    m_MyObject->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
    m_MyObject->show();
    m_MyObject->close();
    delete m_MyObject;

Comment: i did this but still memory leaks occurs.

Comment: Remove m_MyObject->close(); delete m_MyObject;

Comment: Removed  m_MyObject->close(); ,result is same .

Comment: what about delete m_MyObject; ?

Comment: if I dont call show() function than there is no memory leaks happen.

Comment: As I said, the problem is that you `delete` object while it is shown. You must not `delete` it here. You should `delete` it after it is closed (e.g. using `m_MyObject->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);`)

Comment: i did m_MyObject->close();,than deleted it but some memory is not being free.            we have m_MyObject->show() is there any counter function which can completely remove all memory used by this function. this function is creating some memory leak.

Comment: It looks like we have some misunderstanding. I've added an example.

Comment: Actually i want to create one temporary window than i want to delete it ,this temporary window would show some massage i designed this class using base class as QWidget . when i create its object and than delete it increases stack size by one MB after long time my app crashes because of stack overflow.